# Network shares not available, little Xes

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, smb

Sometimes I get this error that all most of the shared folders I see are greyed-out with little Xes and not accessible. A reboot or logout usually fixes the issue, however this keeps happening.
Some folders that I can open usually were the ones created by me, or with some modified files from me. However I do not see the full files on them.
What could be causing this?

Environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Large company
- Not admin of the machine
- Shares on internal server

Error below. Names blurred for privacy.

[image: Error]

Comment: Those signify that those files are not available while offline.  If they are set to be, then your Offline File cache may be corrupted.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 My offline files are disabled. Also, I was online when this happened.

Comment: Yup, and because it's disabled may be why the caches are screwy (I just cleaned one similar).  Try enabling Offline Files again, and use its UI to clear your offline and temporary file caches.